# add a delay between lwc and apex excecution

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, promises

I am struggling in one of issue. I have a lwc page where i can upload multiple files and on button click i create filerecords in sfdc and send those files to AWS(Name and some attributes are coming from filerecord created in sfdc)  and after successful creation of files , I create quote record and update filerecord with the quote record.

The logic which i have at apex is where multiple files will be uploaded at once only one quote record will get create.

The issue here is when creating the quote which is the last part of the code , for each filerecord a quote record is getting created.

I want here once the first quote is created , some delay should be there for the 2nd and subsiquent quote records . Here transaction is happening very fast even i tried given some timeout in LWC

```
async createOppRec(e) {
this.filesData.forEach(async res => {
this.filebase64 = contentDocWrapper.fileContent
const createOpp = await this.createOppfileinAzure(oppfilerec, quotesRec, i)
})
}
async  createOppfileinAzure(oppRec, quoteRec, count) {
    this.showSpinner = true
    var fileRefName
    createfiles({ oppFileRecord: JSON.stringify(oppRec), quoteFileRecord: JSON.stringify(quoteRec) })
    .then(result => {
        console.log('result' + result)
        if (result) {
            result.forEach(res => {
                fileRefName = res.fileref
            })
        }
        if (fileRefName !== null && fileRefName !== undefined) {
            var requestOptions = {
                method: 'PUT',
                body: this.filebase64,
                filename: fileRefName,
                crossOrigin: true
            }
            this.showSpinner = true
            try {
                fetch(herokuapi, { body: JSON.stringify(requestOptions), headers: head, method: 'POST', mode: 'cors' })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then(async (responsejson) =>{
                    console.log(responsejson)
                    tempobj.resp = responsejson;
                    const resp1 = await this.timeoutPromise(6000);
                    createQuote({
                        oppFileRecordId: oppfilerecId
                    })
                    .then(result => {
                        console.log('result' + result)
                        this.showSpinner = false
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log('error173' + JSON.stringify(error))
                    })
                })
            } catch (e) {
                tempobj.error = e
                return tempobj
            }
        }

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error173' + JSON.stringify(error))
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `createOppfileinAzure` inside of a loop. Naturally, this will result in one quote per file. Instead, create all the files first, then do the rest:

```
const fileResults = await Promise.allSettled(this.filesData.map(
  (file) => this.createoppfileinAzure(file)
);
const opportunity = await this.createOpportunity(...);
const quote = await this.createQuote(...);
this.updateFiles(fileResults);
```